# Cart>Checkout>Order-Pay Wordpress & PayU

Tags: php, wordpress, payu

I am working on an e-commerce website and I encountered an issue that I have not been able to resolve.

When you perform the payment process established with WordPress and the PayU plugin, the purchase process executes in this order:

> Cart > Checkout > Order-Pay > Payment Platform (PayU)

However I have been trying to force the checkout to follow this order:

> Cart > Checkout > Payment Platform(PayU)

Sadly without success. Can any one give me a hand?

Here are the screenshots:

[1)Checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZO5v.jpg)
[2)Order-Pay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXzJp.jpg)